# What is the meaning of 'professed' in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'professed' mean in the following extract?

> The impatient idealist is almost sure to be led into hatred by the oppositions and disappointments which he encounters in his endeavors to bring happiness to the world. ... Often he will successfully achieve an attitude of philosophic tolerance as regards the apathy of the masses, and even as regards the whole-hearted opposition of **professed** defenders of the status quo.

The two main dictionary definitions of 'professed' (adjective) are:

- (of a quality, feeling, or belief) claimed openly but falsely
- (of a person) openly declared to be

And the definitions of 'profess' (verb) include:

- claim, often falsely, that one has (a quality or feeling)
- affirm one's faith in or allegiance to (a religion or set of beliefs)

I guess the answer to my question can be found in either 2nd bullet point or 4th bullet point above.

Comment: Personally, I prefer [***self-professed***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=professed+experts%2Cself-professed+experts&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in such contexts, but I'm surprised to discover from this usage chart that apparently I'm in the minority here!

Comment: I think the meaning is the first. My father, despite being a professed vegetarian, was caught eating salami.

Comment: My aunt was a professed Catholic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to profess** means to claim, usually with some degree of fervor, that something is true about yourself, typically something important, often very important,  not a trivial fact.

For example:

You can profess your innocence (e.g. when questioned by the police). "I'm innocent!"

You can profess your faith. "I am a devout ________".

You can profess your ignorance (e.g. when someone asks for advice on how to do a particular thing, or how there could be $250,000 missing from the company bank account). "I have no idea!"

You can profess your undying love. "O Juliet, __________"

In professing something to be true about yourself, you can be speaking the truth or lying or deluding yourself, and in that respect profess is no different from assert, state, say, etc.

The phrase  **professed defenders of the status quo**  refers to "those who profess they are defenders of the status quo". The word is often used ironically, to point out that those professing something are not really what they say they are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bullet points 2 & 4 are the relevant ones as the opposition genuinely believe in the status quo. The context gives no reason to believe any falsehood is involved.
So "**… and even as regards the whole-hearted opposition of professed defenders of the status quo**" could be rewritten  " **… and despite the opposition of those, with genuinely held beliefs, who defend the status quo**"